# My VW DSG switched from D to N automatically after heavy slamming on brake

Tags: brakes, vw, golf

I have VW Golf 2016, yesterday I had to press on brakes very strong to avoid a crash.
I figured out the following:

- The Gearbox switched itself automatically from D to N.
- The brake pedal went a little bit lower than usual due to my strong pushing on brakes.

Is that Normal?

Answer (score 2):

Check the motor mounts. If the motor was at high revs letting off the throttle and hitting the brakes hard could have made the motor shift. Since the motor moves independent of the body and the shift lever is mounted to the body,the motor can move enough to pull the shift actuator out of Drive.

Comment: I was driving at around 30 Km/Hr or lower ? I think the motor revs were around 1000 RPM (or 1500 RPM max). Do you think this is considered high revs?

Comment: Also, one more observation, before this problem, when I press on brakes, and then moving the steering wheel in reverse or forward, I hear some noise! could it be related somehow?